# How to know the data type of a field in trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

How can i know the data type of a field inside a trigger. I am able to get the field name and it's value inside a trigger after insert as follows:

```
DECLARE @AfterInserted XML


     SELECT @AfterInserted = (
        SELECT *
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE User_Key = User_Key
        FOR XML RAW, ROOT
    );

    CREATE TABLE #XML(
    FieldName   nvarchar(250),
    Value       nvarchar(250));


    Insert Into #XML(FieldName, Value)
      select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
             T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')
      from @AfterInserted.nodes('/root/row/@*') as T(N)
```

I also need data type of the field too. something like T.N.value('Data-type')?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you converting the entire structure to XML in the first place? And is your code going to be able to handle the case where the trigger processes multiple rows, not just one?

Comment: In my case only one row is processed at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this will work for your purpose, but:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(your_column, 'BaseType')
FROM your_table
```

Will return a column's field type as `NVARCHAR`.

You can also use `Precision`, `Scale`, `MaxLength`, `Collation` and `TotalBytes` as the 2nd parameter for [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx).

Comment: this is returning nvarchar as data type all the time. even my field's data type is int

Comment: not sure why: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(100, 'BaseType')` returns `int` (and I tried it against a table before posting)

Comment: I meant you should use these on the values in `INSERTED` which will be the actual datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use XML to get meta-data related to the table that the Trigger is on.  You can query the system catalog to get the info directly.

The Trigger is an object with an object_id, so the `@@PROCID` system variable will have the `object_id` of the Trigger itself, within the context of the Trigger.

Using the value of `@@PROCID`, you can look in `sys.objects` at the row for that specific `object_id` and the `parent_object_id` field will be the `object_id` of the Table that the Trigger is on.

Using the value of `parent_object_id`, you can query `sys.tables` / `sys.objects` to get table-level info, or query `sys.columns` to get column-level info.

The example below illustrates the above info:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

-- DROP TABLE dbo.TriggerTest
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.TriggerTest') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating TriggerTest...'
    CREATE TABLE dbo.TriggerTest (Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(30), Col3 DATETIME)
END

-- 
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.TR_TriggerTest_IU') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping TR_TriggerTest_IU...'
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.TR_TriggerTest_IU
END
GO

PRINT 'Creating TR_TriggerTest_IU...'
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_TriggerTest_IU
    ON dbo.TriggerTest
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- get Table info
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sys.tables st
    WHERE   st.[object_id] = (  -- get parent_object_id of this Trigger
                                -- which will be the table that the
                                -- Trigger is on
                                SELECT  so.parent_object_id
                                FROM    sys.objects so
                                WHERE   so.[object_id] = @@PROCID
                            )

    -- get Column info
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sys.columns sc
    -- Custom types will repeat values of system_type_id and produce a
    -- cartesian product, so filter using "is_user_defined = 0"
    INNER JOIN  sys.types st
        ON  st.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
        AND st.is_user_defined = 0
    WHERE   sc.[object_id] = (  -- get parent_object_id of this Trigger
                                -- which will be the table that the
                                -- Trigger is on
                                SELECT  so.parent_object_id
                                FROM    sys.objects so
                                WHERE   so.[object_id] = @@PROCID
                            )
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TriggerTest (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 'a', GETDATE())
```